# Drupal views: limit results shown based on CCK field setting

Tags: drupal-6, view, cck

I have a view that pulls in feed items (from various "Owner feeds" to use the feeds module lingo), then sorts them by date (very important). The owner feed has a CCK field for the type of feed (Twitter, Blog, etc.) and a CCK field theoretically to limit the number of feed items displayed in the view. (The reason for the limit is that Twitter dominates, but we want some blogs, etc., so I don't want to have to show 100 tweets before displaying my first blog.)

I'm guessing some sort of Views hook code is in order, but I'm not sure which one. Perhaps the hook that allows direct modification of the query...

Note that the Owner feed nid is being pulled into the view via a Relationship.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using the Arguments field in the view, you could first select the node type, then node post date.

In this way you could give priority to the blog type, before sorting by date.

You could also consider building two Views, for instance the top 5 blog items  and the top 20 Twitter feeds...

Comment: Thanks but I'm afraid both blogs and tweets are of type "feed item"

Comment: Sorry, my misunderstanding... I was referring to that line:" The owner feed has a CCK field for the type of feed..."